# Execute python on Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

Is there a way to execute python code on a Django Queryset?

I am storing data in the db as bytes and I want to convert them to "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB". Is there any way I can convert the them before passing to the view?

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
 
        context['user'] = (
           DataVolume.objects.values('user')
            .order_by('user')
            .annotate(  imgs=Sum('imgs'), 
                        size=SumConvertBytes('user_bytes'),
                        ),
        )
```

Comment: This doesn't belong in the queryset...

Comment: I agree that doing this with a template filter is preferable. But if you're in a situation where you need to do things that are more complex than belong in a template filter, you can iterate the queryset in the view and modify the data before providing it to the context. Class-based views have enough interdependencies that it takes some care, more than functional views need, (one reason I try to avoid using them) but templates can work fine with a queryset that has been resolved and its in-memory objects modified. Not the best choice here, but sometimes it's necessary.

Comment: An alternative to a template filter is a model method that can be called in a template as `{{object.mymethod}}` (it can also be a property). Useful if the same is sometimes wanted elsewhere in Python code.

Comment: @nigel222: yes, but here `.values(..)` is used, turning the objects into dicts, so there is no way to add a property on these.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting does *not* belong in the queryset, but in the template. Django already has the [**`|filesizeformat`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat):

In the queryset you thus simply sum, and in the template you render with:

```
{{ size|filesizeformat }}
```